# Information Criterion usage to determine number of PCA factors

Tags: pca, econometrics, factor-analysis

I'm reading Ng and Bai 2002: [Determining the Number of Factors in Approximate Factor Models](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.415.7505&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and on the top of page 201 they say:

Let $\sigma$ by a consistent estimate of $(NT)^{-1}\sum_{N}\sum_{T} E(e_{ij})^2$ and then provide a set of Information Criterion using $\sigma$ and $V(k,F^{k})$.  They then define $V(k,F^{k})$ slightly below that as $N^{-1}\sum_{N}\sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i = e_i'*e_i/T$ where $e_i$ are the error vectors associated with column i.

My question is what is the difference between $V(k,F^k)$ and $\sigma$?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V(k,F^k)$ is a sample-specific, model-specific estimate of $\sigma$. Of course, sample statistics and population parameters will be different, but in this case, you also need to account for the fact that your model (the number of factors retained), also influences the variability of this estimate.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how Ng and Bai modify $V$ depending on the number of factors?

Comment: I could be wrong, but they aren't modifying $V$, they are proposing three different info-criteria measures (comparable to Mallow's $C_p$)...you pick the factor based on the model with the lowest information criteria (and they just happen to suggest three options)

Comment: yes but they include both $V$ and $\sigma$ in almost all of the criterion.  Why would they have 2 variables for the same statistic?  I'm mainly curious for implementation reasons

Comment: $V$ is not technically the same as $\sigma$, it is based on the $\sigma_i$ from each factor...I don't think these can be interpreted as the same statistic (unless the model is correct...i.e., the number of factors is correct)

Comment: I am somewhat following but unsure.  Purely for implementation reasons could you explain the formula for $V$ and $\sigma$ and what the difference is for a given factor model with k factors?  Feel free to put it in the answer and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I perform Principle Component based estimation of static factors from macro-panels, with r determined by Bai and Ng (2002) criteria. My N=39 and T=145.

I would like to determine r using my result:

[image: result]

How can I do it?